# Getting error while applying the RegexpTokenizer

Tags: tokenize, sentiment-analysis, tweets

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'w+')
dataset['text'] = dataset['text'].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)
dataset['text'].head()
```

GETTING THIS ERROR:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVWvG.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gOiE.png)

what is the solution for this ??

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7urO.png)

I was expecting this output

Comment: Copy and paste in error messages if possible, rather than using screenshots. Use triple backquotes to surround multiline pre-formatted text. But if you must use screenshots, put the image directly into your question, rather than linking to an externally hosted image.

Comment: One of those screenshots says "expecting string". So my guess is `dataset['text']` is not set correctly. Try printing it and see what it contains.